# updated image on firebase does not render on first click of button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

this is my first stackoverflow question, forgive me if I'm not good at this yet.

long story short I have a react.js application that uses firebase as a DB

My problem is that the image that the user updates to firebase only gets updated by the second click of the imageChangeHandler function.

for example If the user wants to change the image to an apple, it will only update firebase and display the apple when the user clicks the button again and selects the image of a banana.

```
 // STATE
    const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState([]);
    const [newRecipeImage, setNewRecipeImage] = 
    useState(defaultPlateholder);

 // GLOBAL RECIPE DATA FROM FIRESTORE
    const docRef = doc(
      firestore,
      `recipeList/${currentUser.uid}/usersRecipeList`,
      recipeData.id
    );

// FETCHING USERS RECIPE FROM FIRESTORE
   useEffect(() => {
     const fetchingUserRecipes = async () => {
       const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

        if (docSnap.exists()) {
          console.log("Doc data:", docSnap.data()); //this works
          setRecipe(docSnap.data());
        } else {
          console.log("no such document");
        }

        const plateImage = recipe.image;
        setNewRecipeImage(plateImage);
        console.log(newRecipeImage); // this works
     };
     fetchingUserRecipes();
   }, [recipe.image]);

// RECIPE IMAGE - FUNCTION
// This fetches and sets new current state.
   const imageChangeHandler = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const file = e.target.files[0];

     const reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = () => {
       setNewRecipeImage(reader.result);
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    //update firebase to new recipe image
    updateDoc(docRef, {
      image: newRecipeImage,
    });
  };


 {/* RECIPE IMAGE - DISPLAY */}
     return (
       <div className={classes.edit__recipeImageContent}>
          <div className={classes.edit__content_sectionHeader}>
             <h3
               className={`${typography.primary__headingSmall} 
               ${classes.edit__content_sectionTitle}`}
             >
               >> Image of the dish
             </h3>
          </div>

          <div>
          {/* recipe image preview */}
            {recipe.image && (
              <div
                style={{
                  background: recipe.image
                   ? `url("${recipe.image}") no-repeat 
                   center/cover` : null,
                 }}
              ></div>
             )}

          {/* recipe image input */}
          <div className={classes.edit__centerInput}>
            <div className={classes.edit__group}>
              <input
                onChange={imageChangeHandler}
                className={classes.edit__imageInput}
                type="file"
                id="recipeImage"
                name="recipeImage"
                accept="image/*"
                required
              ></input>
              {/* change image button */}
              <label
                htmlFor="recipeImage"
                className={`${button.btn} ${button.btn__primary}`}
              >
                Change image
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
       {/* TESTING PURPOSES ONLY  */}
         <h1>
            this is just to test the new image
            that the user has selected 
         </h1>
         <img src={newRecipeImage} alt="this is a render result 
          test" />
      </div>
     );
```

To explain my code:

In useEffect I check if the recipe data from firebase exists then fetch it and set it as the recipe state. I then set the newRecipeImage state to the image from firebase.

I then created an imageChangeHandler function that allows the user to select a new image from files,
it then sets the newRecipeImage state to the reader result and then updates firebase to the new recipe image.

I would like to render the new image that the user has updated to firebase immediately from the first click of the imageChangeHandler button.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks Doug, I have made the changes that you have requested

Comment: i don't see a button in your code

Comment: other than that, setNewRecipeImage is asynchronous code. this means updateDoc is getting called with the old recipeImage from the imageChangeHandler

Comment: Hi, the button is the input with the onChange handler, what you are saying about the asynchronous makes sense and I think that may be my issue however I used it to render the image immediately. What would you suggest I rather use if not asynchronous to upload and display the new selected image immediately?